# Kentico: Creating WebFormswith Kentico Form Builder with custom form controls

Tags: webforms, customization, kentico, formbuilder, form-control

I've been searching and working around a lot to understand how to create  a Forms using Kentico Form builder with custom form controls that may have special fields and custom validation and totally different styles to adapt to our site design. I've clone the formcontrols but cant just add the class for the style or change validations.

Also how can I get the tooltip of a control form which I clone in the code, I would like to make an special icon for it , move the label from the side to the top of the component and use it inside the form builder but for that I only need to get the tooltip property in the class of the formcontrol which eventhought it has the fields, when debugging it seems to be empty always eventhough in live it actuallly shows the text I put in the tooltip field.

The Documentation is not efficient or clear at all  for these level of customization in Kentico so I would like to know if anyone have pass through the same issues as I and if anyone can help with a better approach to complete my WebForm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've done this plenty of times, but would be useful to see some code because it's not 100% clear what you're trying to achieve. I assume you've started with the example in documentation (https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-form-controls/example-developing-custom-form-controls) which just uses a `asp:DropDownList` which can obviously be wrapped in any style you choose.

Comment: Mind you, you mention moving the label. The form control is just used for the input part of the form. The label is added by the form builder. You'll need a custom form layout to change the wider layout of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that you need to do should be in the **Form controls** application.  In the **General** tab, you need to mark the control as being *High priority*.  To set the special icon, you just need to upload your image to the *Thumbnail* property.

I don't believe that you can change where the labels etc. appear in the form builder.  If you need is to really customize the layout of your form to the end user, you're going to want to look at [custom layouts for the form](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/managing-website-content/forms/defining-custom-form-layout).

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer, I will try with the custom layout form, sometimes it's hard to understand how thinks are implemented in Kentico.
I'll let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I have done this kind of things in past with custom layout and JavaScript to alter the attribute of controls on page load.

This gives us best of both world I.e. power of Kentico to capture, store data and send emails. At the same time it helps to achieve the alteration of look and feel changes on runtime using CSS classes associated at runtime.